# I'm having trouble with creating a interactive menu in Java

Tags: java, class, switch-statement

Our assignment is this https://docs.google.com/document/d/16hHb8WUGehbYLCNrSpJspP8x5GJNCR2q2chnG_yFPSo/pub

and it uses a file which is written here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BxIKe4ZEEpWHmBk2O2FJit6frk5BZSm6SozHOAKWqWU/pub

I am not trying to use this site to have people do my project for me, I would to be pointed in the right direction since I am truly lost.

I am having a bit of trouble with my switch statement and getting the menu to start working.

```
package student;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;


public class TestStudent {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in );
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader( isr );


        String check, tempString, tempString2;
        int tempInt, tempInt2;
        boolean quit = false;

        do
        {
            System.out.println("A - Add student, D - Delete student, F - Find student, H - Help, S - Scores, X - Exit");
            check = stdin.readLine();
            switch (check)
            {

                case "A":
                case "a":
                    System.out.println("Enter the student's name");
                    tempString = stdin.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter the student's ID number");

                //I'm stuck on where to go from here

                case "D":
                case "d":
                    System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the student you wish to delete");
                    tempString = stdin.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Student has been deleted");

                case "F":
                case "f":
                    System.out.println("Enter the Name or ID number of the student you would like to find");
                    tempString = stdin.readLine();
                    System.out.println("");

                case "H":
                case "h":
                    System.out.println("");

                case "S":
                case "s":
                    System.out.println("Enter the Name or ID number of the Student");

                case "X":
                case "x":
                    System.out.println("System shutting down");
            }

       }    //Error saying while is expected     
   }   //Error "Illegal start of an expression
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use a `do-while` loop without the `while`. That is not syntactically correct.

Comment: And also, the switch-case statement without `break;`s is going provide a bit of surprise...

Comment: Can you switch on a string in Java?  I think you need to switch on a char, right?  And yes, where you have the comment `//Error saying while is expected`, needs to be replaced with something like `while (//some condition);

Comment: @nhgrif You can since Java 7.

Comment: In java 7 you can switch strings, but I think you could use check.toUpperCase OR toLowerCase and avoid using 2 cases for each case.

Comment: @porfiriopartida So it would look like this?                                  case "h":
check.toUpperCase
   System.out.println("");

Comment: No.  `switch(check.toLowerCase)` Then make all of your cases lower (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the while in the do.

```
do {
  ...
}while(condition)
```

So I believe you want something like:

```
do {
  ...
  //your whole switch statement
  ...
}while(!quit) //exit when quit is true, stay if quit is not true.
```

Every case should have its own break, otherwise if you go to case A, it will go then to case D and so on.

```
        case "A":
        case "a":
            System.out.println("Enter the student's name");
            tempString = stdin.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the student's ID number");
            break; //add this to every case if you don't want to execute next case.
```

To simplify a bit your switch.. if you use `check = stdin.readLine().toLowerCase();`

you can avoid using 2 cases for 1 case:

case "a" and remove case "A" (cases of Capital letter may be removed)

Finally your while will never end if you don't reset the `quit` value

Maybe you can add another case for it like:

```
case "q":
    quit=true;
    break;
```

There is also a default case that is executed if none of the cases are.

Comment: So I would have a }while after each break; to make the program do what you told it to do?

Comment: @nickkbmod No, the while is independent from the switch, it belongs to the `do` and in this case the switch statement should be inside the `do { ...here... } while(condition)`

Answer (score 0):

[Do-while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loops in Java.  This link will help with some of your problems.